# How to check if a boolean variable is 1/true or 0/false with TinyButStrong?

Tags: php, tinybutstrong

I'm kinda new with TinyButStrong, and I would like to know how I can check if a boolean variable is 0 or 1 ?
For example, I have this:

```
$TBS->MergeBlock('tests', $tests);
```

And $tests have a variable call 'activated' which is a boolean.
So, in my .docx document, I would like to write the string 'Activated' if the variable is set to true(1), and 'non-activated' if it set to false(0).

Which syntax should I use in the .docx document ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `isset($var) or empty($var)` if possible

Comment: Hello, my problem is that I would write the "isset" or "empty" inside my .docx template, something like: [isset(tests.actived)]Activated, I don't want to check in my php script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are several ways to format values during the merging, but by default TBS converts data items into strings using the PHP implicit conversion.

Thus, `true` is converted into '1' and `false` is converted into '' *(empty string)*.

For the non-existing value: If the key in the array you want to merge does not exist, then you can avoid the TBS error message using parameter `noerr`, and the value for replacement is '' *(empty string)*.

So your solution is :

```
[test.ativated;noerr;if [val]=1;then 'Activated';else 'non-activated']
```